# How to determine if array contains an object with an attribute that equals a given value

Tags: arrays, go, arrayobject

I have an array like this, which will the response from the API.

```
[
    {
        "id": "F1eOrsr3g7gad6",
        "created_at": 1591951315,
        "url": "https://example.com",
        "secret": "1234",
        "secret_exists": true
    },
    {
        "id": "FintcvTBaYwPz2",
        "created_at": 1591953315,
        "url": "http://example.com",
        "secret": "34532",
        "secret_exists": true
    }
]
```

How do I check this array has the value "**F1eOrsr3g7gad6**" or not?

I had tried to write a function that will return the index value if the value exists.

```
func isExists(key string, value string, data []map[string]interface{}) (result int) {
    result = -1
    for i, search := range data {
        if search[key] == value {
            result = i
            break
        }
    }
    return result
}
var value string = "FintcvTBaYwPz2"
var key string = "id"
result := isExists(key, value, data) // here data will be the array which I want to pass.
fmt.Println("Result: ", result)
```

Comment: JSON decode the response into a slice struct. Then iterate over the slice to find the matching `id`.

Comment: Use [this site](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) to convert a JSON response into a representative go struct.

Comment: What is your question? What help do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done all the hard work, just change the signature of your function to return a `bool` instead of the index, and return `true` or `false`:

```
func isExists(key string, value string, data []map[string]interface{}) (exists bool) {

    for _, search := range data {
        if search[key] == value {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/lJGwa6pZaX5

Comment: Thanks @colm. I am getting this error When I pass my array of objects as a parameter in my function. `cannot convert arr (type []interface {}) to type []byte`

Comment: Check the playground link I included - it shows how to convert a stream of JSON bytes into a usable go data type.